How to pass multip subnet ids in azurerm_storage_account or azurerm_storage_account_network_rules in Terraform
I am trying to create a storage account in Azure using Terraform and cannot seem to dynamically pass the virtual_network_subnet_ids into the network_rules block or the azurerm_storage_account_network_rules resource block.  It seems to not like adding the dynamic block to the azurerm_storage_account stating "No more than 1 "network_rules" blocks are allowed".  I have multiple storage accounts and am trying to divide the subnets up via passing a variable with the subnet names.
terraform.tfvars
 sa = {
  sta1 = {
    name                    = "storageacct001"
    resource_group_name     = "rg1"
    account_kind            = "StorageV2"
    account_tier            = "Standard"
    replication_type        = "LRS"
    access_tier             = "Hot"
    enable_hierarchical_ns  = false
    enable_sftp             = false
    enable_large_file_share = false
    billingTag              = "billing_project"
    systemTag               = "Azure"
    componentTag            = "Database Backup Files"
    subnets = [
      "subnet1",
      "subnet2",
      "subnet3",
      "subnet4",
      "subnet5",
      "subnet6"
    ]
  }
}

With just using a storage account resource block and not calling a module, i seem to be getting an error each way i build this.
azurerm_storage_account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = var.sa.sta1.name
  ""
  ""
  ""

  network_rules {
    default_action = var.default_network_rule
    bypass         = var.traffic_bypass
    ip_rules       = var.aamva_vpn_ip_address
    dynamic "virtual_network_subnet_ids" {
      for_each = var.sa.sta1.subnets
      content {
        virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.vnet-subnets[virtual_network_subnet_ids.value].id]
      }
    }
  }
}

Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on sa.tf line 34, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa":
│   34:     dynamic "virtual_network_subnet_ids" {
│
│ Blocks of type "virtual_network_subnet_ids" are not expected here.



resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
      name                     = var.sa.sta1.name
      ""
      ""
      ""
 dynamic "network_rules" {
    for_each = var.sa.sta1.subnets 
    content {
    default_action = var.default_network_rule
    bypass         = var.traffic_bypass
    ip_rules       = var.aamva_vpn_ip_address
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.vnet-subnets[network_rules.value].id]
    }
  }

│ Error: Too many network_rules blocks
│
│   on sa.tf line 32, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa":
│   32:     content {
│
│ No more than 1 "network_rules" blocks are allowed

azurerm_storage_account_network_rules
 resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa" {
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.sa.id
    ""
    ""
    ""
    dynamic "virtual_network_subnet_ids" {
        for_each = var.sa.sta1.subnets
        content {
          virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.vnet-subnets[virtual_network_subnet_ids.value].id]
        }
      }
    }
    │ Error: Unsupported block type
    │
    │   on sa.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa":
    │   43:   dynamic "virtual_network_subnet_ids" {
    │
    │ Blocks of type "virtual_network_subnet_ids" are not expected here.

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
          name                     = var.sa.sta1.name
          ""
          ""
          ""
 network_rules {
    default_action = var.default_network_rule
    bypass         = var.traffic_bypass
    ip_rules       = var.aamva_vpn_ip_address
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      network_rules
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet" {
  for_each                   = toset(var.sa.sta1.subnets)
  storage_account_id         = azurerm_storage_account.sa.id
  default_action             = var.default_network_rule
  bypass                     = var.traffic_bypass
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.vnet-subnets[each.value].id]

}

Plan: 7 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/<tenant>/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageacct001" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_storage_account_network_rule" for more information.
│
│   with azurerm_storage_account_network_rules.sa-subnet["subnet1"],
│   on sa.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet":
│   43: resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/<tenant>/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageacct001" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_storage_account_network_rule" for more information.
│
│   with azurerm_storage_account_network_rules.sa-subnet["subnet2"],
│   on sa.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet":
│   43: resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/<tenant>/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageacct001" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_storage_account_network_rule" for more information.
│
│   with azurerm_storage_account_network_rules.sa-subnet["subnet3"],
│   on sa.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet":
│   43: resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "sa-subnet" {
│

I am not sure how I can dynamically pass the subnet_ids into the storage account network_rule from a list of subnet names.  It seems the only way i can deploy this is if I hardcode the subnet_ids into the subnet block in the terraform.vars file.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Also, there will be more storage accounts in the sa variable, I just listed one.

While youre dynamically passing subnet IDs to the network_rules block in azurerm_storage_account, try  use a data "azurerm_subnet" lookup for each subnet in your list and assign the virtual_network_subnet_ids array in a single network_rules block @NickP


Passing multiple subnet ids in azurerm_storage_account or azurerm_storage_account_network_rules in Terraform

The issue seems to be with the way you pass
virtual_network_subnet_ids as you tried to pass them dynamically.
To achieve this set subnet IDs for network_rules, use a data block to fetch all subnet details and then use loop to list the subnet IDs without refering them directly.
Configuration:
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "testsamplevnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnets" {
  for_each = toset(var.sa.sta1.subnets)

  name                 = each.key
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = var.sa.sta1.name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = var.sa.sta1.account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.sa.sta1.replication_type
  account_kind                     = var.sa.sta1.account_kind
  access_tier              = var.sa.sta1.access_tier

  network_rules {
    default_action             = var.default_network_rule
    bypass                     = var.traffic_bypass
    ip_rules                   = var.aamva_vpn_ip_address
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [for subnet in data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnets : subnet.id]
  }

  tags = {
    Billing    = var.sa.sta1.billingTag
    System     = var.sa.sta1.systemTag
    Component  = var.sa.sta1.componentTag
  }
}

deployment:


Refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account_network_rules
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

this works, but i feel this might increase the number of data blocks as i start adding more and more storage accounts in

To avoid multiple data blocks for each storage account, use a single data.azurerm_subnet block with a loop to fetch all subnet IDs dynamically. Then pass the list of subnet IDs to the network_rules block in each storage account using a variable for subnets.

this approach will helps you with blocker you mentioned

I do have a data block that get all the subnets on vnets, however i am struggling getting that information into a list, from a specific list of subnets per storage account.
data "azurerm_subnet" "vnet-subnets" {
for_each             = toset(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets)
name                 = each.value
virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
}
Trying to place the subnets in the tfvars into a list, pulled from here

try Using a data "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnets" block with for_each = toset(var.sa.sta1.subnets) to retrieve specified subnets dynamically. Then, in the network_rules block of the storage account, use virtual_network_subnet_ids = [for subnet in var.sa.sta1.subnets : data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnets[subnet].id] to pass the list of subnet IDs directly. This keeps it dynamic and scalable.

I have the data block of all the subnets already, i was just wondering if there is a way to pull a specifc set of subnets IDs from the data block and create a subnet ID list to be passed inline in the network_rules block.  It seems there is no way to do this, without creating a seperate data block with the just the var.sa.sta1.subnets, but then var.sa.sta2.subnets will be a list of different subnets so will create another data block.

I think here you can achieve this by filtering the existing data block using toset(var.sa.staX.subnets) where staX refers to each storage account. Use virtual_network_subnet_ids = [for subnet in var.sa.staX.subnets : data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnets[subnet].id] directly in each storage account resource to dynamically pull only the required subnet IDs, without needing separate data blocks.
